# Set select rails with no related model collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to setup a combobox with a no related model collection, it will be displayed in my Stand model new view, but they are not related directly.

It is like show the classic country -> state -> city relation form where country and city are not directly related, so what I want to do is just show a "country" combo when I am creating a new city to display just related states! PLS HELP! IM DYING DOING THIS!

I want to do something like this:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <% 
          concat f.cr_ubicacion.select :codpabellon, 
          Mtopabellon.order(:nombre), :codpabellon, :nombre, {}, 
          {class: "store-select"}
        %>
      </div>
```

Comment: So, you want a simple `select`? If so, what is the problem? Or please show your current attempt.

Comment: well yeah its a simple select inside a form, but the model collection i want to use is not related to the actual model im using, lets say I want to create a new city, so I need to have the country select on view! Ive updated the post

Comment: If you've solved it, just add it as an answer, instead of inside the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

```
        <% 
          concat f.select :idubicacion, Mtopabellon.all.collect {|p| [ 
          p.nombre, p.codpabellon ] }, {prompt: 'Seleccione una 
          pabellon'}, :class=>'form-control', :id => 'cmbPab'
        %>
```

Just setup the collection I needed even using a different :idubicacion and it works!